# head bang: why is ufw allowing this traffic

Tags: firewall, ufw

Given these ufw rules :

```
ufw status verbose
2001:nnn:0:400b::12        DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)             
2001:nnn:0:400b::12        DENY OUT    Anywhere (v6)
```

Why is this request out and response in allowed  :

```
ping6 2001:nnn:0:400c::12
PING 2001:nnn:0:400c::12(2001:4e8:0:400c::12) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:nnn:0:400c::12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=15.9 ms
```

There must be some basic concept about firewall rules that I'm not getting. To my learner's mind, the request out should be denied. And even if that slips by, the response should be denied.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to enable ufw firewall to allow icmp response?](https://askubuntu.com/a/10314/178692)

Comment: @steeldriver My question was confusing. I hope I've made it more clear by removing the reference to ping.I'm trying to block *any* traffic to that IP.

Comment: My point was that (AFAIK), `ufw` doesn't really "do" ICMP