# Cant ping with UFW enabled

Tags: 20.04, dns, firewall, ufw, ping

I am having an issue with UFW on Ubuntu 20.04. I am running a Nextcloud server on this machine, and my default is to deny incoming and outgoing, except for port 443 which works fine. This is causing some issues for Nextcloud as it can't resolve hostnames it needs to work.

When I try to ping google.com, it says temporary failure in name resolution, and when I ping 8.8.8.8 it returns sendmsg: Operation not permitted

Once UFW is disabled, both of these work fine. I would rather not just open port 53, since that may introduce other vulnerabilities.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work? Thanks!

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/q/6995